How to Set Breakpoints in mdbg.exe?
I'm trying to use mdbg.exe for debugging C# code from the command line, replicating this tutorial. I've installed Mdbg.exe as explained here.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CSharpFundamentals
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            var smallests = GetSmallests(numbers, 3);

            foreach (var number in smallests)
                Console.WriteLine(number);
        }

        public static List<int> GetSmallests(List<int> list, int count)
        {
            var smallests = new List<int>();

            while (smallests.Count < count)
            {
                var min = GetSmallest(list);
                smallests.Add(min);
                list.Remove(min);
            }

            return smallests;
        }

        public static int GetSmallest(List<int> list)
        {
            // Assume the first number is the smallest
            var min = list[0];
            for (var i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (list[i] > min)
                    min = list[i];
            }
            return min;
        }
    }
}

I compiled the code with:
csc /debug+ /pdb:Program.pdb Program.cs

Then I ran:
mdbg Program.exe

This gave me the following output:
MDbg (Managed debugger) v0.0.0.0 started.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
For information about commands type "help";
to exit program type "quit".
run Program.exe
STOP: Breakpoint Hit
located at line 9 in Program.cs
[p#:0, t#:0] mdbg>

However, when I try to set a breakpoint using either of these commands:
break Program.cs 10

or
b Program.cs 10

I get the error:

Error: Invalid breakpoint syntax.

I've checked the help menu (? command), but it doesn't provide examples for setting breakpoints. What is the correct syntax for setting a breakpoint in mdbg.exe?


I found the solution to this issue. Here's how to set breakpoints in mdbg.exe:

Correct syntax for setting a breakpoint:
break <filename>:<line_number>

or using the shorthand:
b <filename>:<line_number>

For example:
break Program.cs:10

or
b Program.cs:10


Regarding the initial "Breakpoint Hit" message:
mdbg.exe automatically sets a breakpoint at the entry point of the program. This is why I saw a breakpoint hit at line 9 without explicitly setting one.


